# How to make a Qtime with 1MHz of refresh?

Tags: qt

I´m new in programming and I´m working with a haptic device ([Phantom Omni "Sensable"](http://www.sensable.com/haptic-phantom-omni.htm)), these haptic I have to integrate with Qt because my GUI is done there, so I must have a minimum 1MHz Qtimer but I can´t found how to do these?

Please Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you need to update your device 1 million times per second (1MHz)? I quickly checked Sensable's Programmer’s Guide (which may or may not be applicable to your device) and according to that only 1kHz update frequency is used.

Answer (score 2):

QTimer does not get higher resolution that 1 ms.  You will need to override the appropriate event handlers if you need to process events faster than 1000 Hz.  Even then, you are probably not guaranteed anything in particular about performance.

You could write a QThread that does its own timing with a high-resolution timer, and communicates results back to the main thread.